# Why is Powershell ISE showing errors that Powershell console does not show?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0, powershell-ise

I'm running exactly the same script.ps1 file in a Powershell ISE (manually loading the script and pressing F5) and in a Powershell console (executing the script file). **They both work but ISE shows errors that the console does not. Why?**

The code is:

```
git push origin master
Write-Host "lastExitCode: $lastExitCode Last command was successful: $?"
```

This code output this error in the ISE:

```
git.cmd : Initializing to normal mode
At E:\script.ps1:28 char:4
+ git <<<<  push origin master
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Initializing to normal mode:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Initializing to normal mode

Everything up-to-date

lastExitCode: 0 Last command was successful: False
```

And this in the console:

```
Everything up-to-date
lastExitCode: 0 Last command was successful: True
```

You can see that the success status is not the same also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why they output differently, but the message that we see from `git push` is coming over stderr. This means that they are **both** showing errors, although the ISE is making them much louder, and converting it into error ***objects***.

Consider this output from the PowerShell prompt:

```
PS> git push
Everything up-to-date
PS> git push 2> $null    # Redirect stderr to $null
PS> $LastExitCode
1
PS>
```

and compare it to the ISE:

```
PS> git push
git : Everything up-to-date
At line:1 char:1
+ git push
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Everything up-to-date:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
PS> git push 2> $null
PS> $LastExitCode
1
PS>
```

Except for the extra output from the error object being displayed, the output is the same. The ISE has converted the stderr string to a NativeCommandError object, and it does even display the error message if you look past the red.

Comment: Were you able to figure this issue out? I'm also running into this behavior.

Comment: If you redirect the output to `$null`, you should be able to avoid the differences in the messages, and just check `LastExitCode` to see what it did.

Answer (score 4):

as shown in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751261/powershell-displays-some-git-command-results-as-error-in-console-even-though-ope) to prevent `git push` to print to STDERR the solution is to call the command witn `--porcelain` option.

then, calling

> `git push origin master --porcelain`

output goes all to STDOUT

Answer (score 2):

So, the example below case have any error , this command  -q **2>&1** | %{ "$_" }` will nullifying the result of errors.

A solution and use: `git push   -q 2>&1 | %{ "$_" }`

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, the only major difference I can think of right off the top of my head is that the ISE uses single-threaded apartment (STA) mode in v2, and the console uses multi-threaded apartment (MTA). Have you tried running powershell.exe with the -STA argument, or powershell_ise.exe with -MTA, and trying the script again?

It looks like the error is coming from the Git command you're trying to run, FWIW.