# Git Clone generating an error in Azure Command Line Task

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my Azure DevOps CD pipeline, I have added a Command Line task which clones a Git repository. The clone is done successfully however there is an error in the log.

The strange behavior is that the clone works perfectly with an Azure hosted agent (like *vs2017-win2016* or *windows-2019*) but generates the error (see below screenshot) if I use a private local agent.

Command Line Script:

```
git config --global user.email "my@email.com"
git config --global user.name "naregk"
git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" https://naregk.visualstudio.com/txproject/_git/RepoD testrepoD
```

The stage outcome:

[image]

The error which appears:

> 57.7114907Z ##[command]"C:\Nindows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C 
>   "CALL "C:\agent_work_temp\aae38ede—905d—4d6d-9412-0
>   57.96819332 ##[error]Cloning into 'testrepoD'...
>   06.96751142 ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some git command output can be `stderr` (instead of `stdout`) and PowerShell think it's an error.

To solve it, you can do something like this:

```
$result = git clone -c ....... testrepoD 2>&1
Write-Host $result
```

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820975/git-clone-redirect-stderr-to-stdout-but-keep-errors-being-written-to-stderr) might give some more ideas how to deal with this situation.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko and @Shayki Abramczyk, thanks for the tips. My solution was to use PowerShell and not Command Line task and added `$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'` before the the `git` commands.

Comment: @naregkar you're welcome! only now I saw you specified command line in the question... and I answered with PowerShell script... sorry! your solution is also good :)