# git clone writes to stderr

Tags: node.js, git

When I run a git clone command using `child_process.exec` it outputs to `stderr` instead of `stdout`

```
const proc = child_process.exec(bashCommand, {
      cwd
    });

    proc.stdout.on("data", data => {
      debug && console.log(data);
      outputCB && outputCB(data);
    });

    proc.stderr.on("data", data => {
      debug && console.error(data); // THIS FIRES
      errorCB && errorCB(data);
    });
```

How do I get it to output non-errors to `stdout` while still outputting REAL errors to `stderr`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34820975/7976758