# Why doesn't redirection of the output of "nohup git clone" write to a text file?

Tags: git, io-redirection, nohup

```
$ > nohup git clone https://github.com/arepo.git >nohup.txt &
$ > tail -F nohup.txt
nohup: ignoring input
Cloning into 'arepo'...
```

Why do the outputs that normally follow (when outputting to bash) disappear when I use `nohup`?

Related, but separate from:

- [git repository cloning logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719936/git-repository-cloning-logging)
- [git clone writes to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654812/git-clone-writes-to-stderr)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+redirect+output

Comment: It's not due to `nohup`, it's due to redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--progress` option like:

```
nohup git clone --progress https://github.com/arepo.git >nohup.txt &
```

Apparently, the progress status is only reported when attached to a terminal unless you set this option:
https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---progress