# Suppress output from Git command in PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, io-redirection

As part of a script I am running `git clean -fd`.  It typically outputs a bunch of files that are cleaned up. I would like to suppress this output.

I tried `git clean -fd | Out-Null` but it did not seem to work.  Googling returned no options for `git` to suppress output, so is there another PowerShell method I can use? Or am I doing something wrong?  It may be worth noting that the PowerShell script itself is being executed from within a `.bat` file.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279007/error-when-pulling-from-powershell-script/57316495#57316495

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add option [`-q`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt--q):

```
git clean -fdq
```

Answer (score 8):

[phd's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538834/45375) offers the best solution for the case at hand.

As for why `... | Out-Null` wasn't effective:

**`Out-Null` suppresses only *stdout* output from external programs** such as `git`, but not *stderr* output.

`git`, like many CLIs (console / terminal programs), uses the stderr stream not just to report *errors*, but also for *status information* - basically, anything that's *not data*.

To suppress *both* stdout and stderr output, use `*> $null`:

```
git clean -fd *> $null
```

Note: **`*> $null` suppresses *all* output streams**; while *external programs* only have *2* (stdout and stderr), applying `*>$null` to a *PowerShell-native command* silences *all 6* output streams.

See [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) for more information.

---

#### Optional reading: *Selective* stream redirection from external programs:

Building on feedback from [nmbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5034468/nmbell):

- `>$null` (or `1>$null`) can be used to suppress *stdout* output *selectively*, which is effectively the same as `| Out-Null`.
- `2>$null` can be used to suppress *stderr* output *selectively*.
- `*>$null`, as discussed above, silences *both* (all) streams.

Of course, instead of `$null` for *suppressing* output, the redirection target may also may be a *file* (name or path).

Note:

- PowerShell processes output from external programs *line by line* in its pipeline, and if the output is captured in a *variable* (`$out = ...`) and comprises *2 or more lines*, it is stored as an *array* (`[object[]]`) of lines (strings).
- PowerShell only ever "speaks text" (uses strings) with external programs, both when sending and receiving data, which means that *character-encoding issues* may come into play.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980675/45375) for more information on both these aspects.

---

**Scenarios with examples**:

Setup:

```sh
# Construct a platform-appropriate command, stored in a script block ({ ... }) 
# that calls an external program (the platform-native shell) that outputs
# 1 line of stdout and 1 line of stderr output each, and can later be 
# invoked with `&`, the call operator.
$externalCmd = if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {     # Windows
                 { cmd /c 'echo out & echo err >&2' } 
               } else {                            # Unix (macOS, Linux)
                 { sh -c 'echo out; echo err >&2' } 
               }
```

---

**Capture stdout, pass stderr *through*:**

```
PS> $captured = & $externalCmd; "Captured: $captured"
err            # Stderr output was *passed through*
Captured: out  # Captured stdout output.
```

---

**Capture stdout, *suppress* stderr output, with `2>$null`:**

```
PS> $captured = & $externalCmd 2>$null; "Captured: $captured"
Captured: out  # Captured stdout output - stderr output was suppressed.
```

---

**Capture *both* stdout and stderr, with `*>&1`:**

```
PS> $captured = & $externalCmd *>&1 | % ToString; "Captured: $captured"
Captured: out err  # *Combined* stdout and stderr output.
```

Note:

- `% ToString` is short for `ForEach-Object ToString`, which calls the `.ToString()` method on each output object, which ensures that the [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances that PowerShell wraps *stderr* lines in are converted back to *strings*.
- `$captured` receives a 2-element *array* (`[object[]]`) of lines - containing the stdout and stderr line as elements, respectively; it is [PowerShell's string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) that turns them into a single-line, space-separated string in this case.

---

**Capture *only stderr*, suppress stdout:**

```
PS> $captured = 
      & $externalCmd *>&1 | 
        ? { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] } | 
          % ToString; "Captured: $captured"
Captured: err  # Captured stderr output *only*.
```

Note:

- `? { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }` is short for
  `Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }`, which passes only stderr lines - identifiable via the wrapper type being tested for - through, and `% ToString` again converts them back to strings.
- This technique is neither obvious nor convenient; [GitHub suggestion #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332) proposes a syntax such as `2> variable:stderr` to support redirecting streams to *variables*, such as `$stderr` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @nmbell: I've have folded your feedback into the answer and have fleshed it out; please see the newly added bottom section.