# How to Check-in a file in BitBucket Repository with TFS CI Build Definition?

Tags: git, bitbucket, azure-pipelines, bitbucket-pipelines, tfs-2017

**The situation:**

I am new to BitBucket.
I currently I have a repository created in BitBucket and I have a TFS CI build definition with which I have linked the BitBucket Repository through an Endpoint.

The TFS CI Build Definition basically downloads the Readme.md file, which is checked-in in that repository.

**Problem 1:**

I want to know how can I upload\check-in any file\folders into that repository present on Bitbucket with TFS CI Build?

[image]

**Problem 2:**

In the triggers option of CI build, I don't see the option of Gated trigger present under it, like it used to be when I use TFS as the source code repository.

[image]

After creating a batch file,

Batch file script - It works successfully if triggered manually but doesn't work with TFS build.

[image]

TFS Build Pipeline which gets stuck at the Git push command while executing the batch file.

[image]

Comment: check-in and "Gated" trigger it's for TFVC code. Bitbucket is Git repo, totally different.

Comment: So, does that means It is not possible to push the code to Bitbucket Repo with TFS build? If it is possible then how can I do that ?

Comment: You can do it. But why you want to push code from a build? Is not a best practice.

Comment: Actually, we are going to use those repos present on bitbucket for pushing any code but to check-in some configuration files in that repo.  That will be used and downloaded on another domain where currently the TFS source code repository is not supported. However, if it is possible to push any file to the bitbucket repo thorugh TFS could you please let me know how, is there is any link that i can refer?

Answer (score 0):

We can use git command to push the file.
Steps:

1. Create a build pipeline
2. Add task Command line and enter the code. Please refer to this [doc](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/push-updates-to-a-repository/)  for more details.

   ```
    git config --global user.email ""
    git config --global user.name ""
    git init
    git remote add {BitBucket repo git URL}
    git checkout -b {branch name}
    git add {file path}
    git commit -m "xxx"
    git remote add origin {BitBucket repo git URL}
    git push -u origin {branch name}
   ```

Comment: I have created a similar batch file which when executed manually does commits and pushes the file to bitbucket repo successfully but when same batch file is called through build pipeline it gets stuck on git push command for hours and doesn't pushes the file to bitbucket. I am attaching the screenshot of both above TFS build and batch script, do you know what would be the reason it is getting stuck at Git push?

Comment: Please set the variable system.debug to true, then share the latest log screenshot and build definition with us. I will check it and update the answer to help you resolve the issue.
In addition, There is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279007/error-when-pulling-from-powershell-script), please also check it.